# Most performant way to use a background image throughout an iphone application

Tags: iphone, uikit

I have an image that I want to use as the background for every view in my application including several modal views.

Right now I'm just creating a new UIColor for each view:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"metal-bg.png"]];
```

This works for the most part but with the modal views there is a brief period during the sliding animation before the background image displays when I can see through the modal view to the view below it.

Is there a better way to do this? 
Such as setting up some sort of global object that all the views can use?

Comment: Maybe add it to the window and set all the other views to clear (or alpha = 0.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the background image in `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`?

Comment: Can I unload that background image in `viewDidDisappear` to save memory by clearing the background color?

Comment: Well, since `UIColor colorWithPatternImage:` is a convenience method, I believe the system manages the memory allocation and releasing.

Comment: Meh. I don't like that. Convenience methods don't always work efficiently. Thanks though.

Comment: @Moshe Well, you don't have to use a convenience method.  You could use `self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourPic.png"]];` then release it when done, but there really is no need.

Comment: There is in my app, heh. I am making an app that is re-using this one image a lot.

Comment: @Moshe I didn't mean there was no need to release it, I meant there is no need to **not** use the convenience method.  Just confused myself with double negatives. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was just wondering about this yesterday.

I haven't tried this, but I suspect that it may be possible to add a UIImage to the Application's delegate and then use that image in every view.

**Try this:**

[`self.view setBackgroundColor:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] bgImageColor]];`

Comment: But you're still setting the background color from an image file.  Doesn't need to be added to the delegate IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add a subview that contains the image as the bottom view of the `window` object in the app delegate. Then, for any views that you add on top, you can do: `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` (assuming it's a `UIViewController` or one of its children that you're using).